# How to show image inside notification payload with firebase cloud functions in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show Photo inside notification payload using firebase cloud functions in Android.
I want to achieve something like this as shown in screenshot.[image]

My cloud function payload code is here:

```
    message = {
      notification: {
        title: username,
        body: content,
        image: profileImageUrl,  // I'm passing image url as image parameter
      },
      token: deviceToken,
    };

    return admin
      .messaging()
      .send(message)
      .then(async (response) => {
        return console.log(
          "Successfully sent notification:",
          deviceToken
        );
      })
      .catch(async (error) => {
        return console.log("Error sending notification:", error);
      });
  })
  .catch(async (error) => {
    return console.log("Error:", error);
  });
```

Following code is not working out

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
const message = { 
    notification: {  
      title: 'Sparky says hello!' 
    },
     android: {  
      notification: {   
        imageUrl: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'  
      } 
    },
     apns: {  
      payload: {   
        aps: {    
          'mutable-content': 1   
        }  
      },
        fcm_options: {   
        image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'  
      } 
    },
```

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

Comment: Folks, for android this is not working.

Comment: For Android you should put the key "image" and not "imageUrl" and under notification and not "android / notification"

Answer (score 1):

"notification": {

```
"title": "Sparky says hello!",

"image": "https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png"
```

}